# Usage of palette argument in scale_*_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Background**

The help of `?scale_fill_manual` says:

> ```
>  ...: Arguments passed on to ‘discrete_scale’
>           palette A palette function that when called with a single
>               integer argument (the number of levels in the scale)
>               returns the values that they should take.
> ```

---

**Code**

Thus, I tried:

```
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

my_pal <- colorRampPalette(1:3)

(p <- ggplot(mtcars %>% 
              group_by(cyl) %>% 
              summarise(mpg = mean(mpg)), 
             aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
   geom_col())
```

---

**Problem**

But if I want to add my palette function to the scale it does not work:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(palette = my_pal)
# Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
#   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
```

---

**Question**

How do I use the `palette` argument properly? I know how I can set the color properly, but I want to understand what the `palette` argument is for and how to use it. If it is an internal argument, I was wondering why it is available in the `scale_*_manual` API in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure you're using `colorRampPalette` correctly? Try this syntax: `p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2")`

Comment: Well, the doc says I should provide a function which takes a single integer argument. That's what `colorRampPalette(1:3)` does, it creates a function which returns `n` colors interpolated between the colors passed to it (in this case colors `1-3`). The `palette` argument for  `scale_fill_brewer` is indeed different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. See the (closed) issue: [scale_colour_manual(palette=foo): cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3182):

@sjackman:

> How is the `palette` argument meant to be used; is there an example in the documentation?

@clauswilke:

> It's not meant to be used at all. The bug is that `palette` is accessible and mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, but that explains it very well, thanks! +1